# How to set the default file saving name when user click download link?

Tags: javascript, html, download, rename

I've got a download link on page:
    `<a href="124463.mp3">xxxx</a>`
When user click it, the default file name on the pop up saving dialog is `124463.mp3`, but now I want to change it to some better name. If there is no way to change the file's name on server, How to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the name of an html download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037273/changing-the-name-of-an-html-download)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with an HTTP header. Apparently it's `Content-disposition: attachment; filename=your_name_here.mp3`. I don't know if you can do this from javascript or html, though. You definitely can using php.

From http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/forcedownload.html

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I am trying to write an php as a proxy to solve this problem, and, maybe that's a way to solve cross-domain issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the download attribute to the save as file name, and the href attribute to the original filename.

```html
<a href="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_1MG.mp3" download="save-as-file-name.mp3">Download</a>
```