# Change name of download in javascript

Tags: html, javascript

If a user clicks on a downloadable link such as

```
<a href="downloadable.txt">Download</a>
```

Is there a client-side (html or javascript) way to change the name of the file before the 'Save As' dialog?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the name of an html download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037273/changing-the-name-of-an-html-download)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, you cannot change this from the client side (HTML or javascript). You need to change it from the server. One way is to use a server side script which will set the Content-Disposition HTTP response header:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=somecustomname.txt
```

Comment: Although not client-side, this is the effect I wanted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 100):

HTML5 provides the [`a[download]`](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download) attribute which lets you rename a file.  This example will download `link.txt` and rename it `something.txt`.

```
​<a download="something.txt" href="link.txt">asdf</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Note that this only works on same-origin URLs (i.e. not across different domains).

Comment: Not only Chrome anymore, it also works on my Firefox 28.0.
You can see the compatibility list here : http://caniuse.com/download

Comment: Works in Firefox starting in version 20.0, but only for files from the same domain (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download)

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=download  Now is supported in Opera and android browser.

Comment: do you guys know if it works for all file types or just something basic like .txt?

Comment: @ElonZito Should work for anything - it's just a file name.  Is something not working that you expect to?

Comment: @Dennis I think my issue was IIS server rules overwriting the download naming convention. Thanks!

Comment: download attribute is ignored if server side did sent Content-Disposition header with filename (as stated here: https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a )

Comment: > If the header specifies a disposition of inline, Chrome and Firefox prioritize the attribute and treat it as a download. Old Firefox versions (before 82) prioritize the header and will display the content inline.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#download

Answer (score 4):

You can use Filesaver.js script written by eligrey(Im using angularjs in the example here)
You can achieve the same in classic javascript using XmlHttpRequest object

```
//In your html code , add these : ->
<script src="https://rawgit.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
//In your Javascript:- 

$http({
        url: "url where the file is located",
        method: "GET",
        responseType: "blob"
    }).then(function (response) {

saveAs(response.data,"newfilename.extension");

})
```