# add download function to a click event with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, download

I am wondering if it is possible to add a download function to a click event purely in Javascript, for example, when a user clicks on an image, it gets automatically downloaded. For example I have an image tag `<img src="filelocation" id="img"/>` and want it to be downloaded on click. (I can't use `"download="myfile.png"`.

Is there something like

```
$('#img').on('click',function(e){
  img.download="myfile.png";
});
```

All the answers online suggest adding the `download="..."` into my tag

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this:

```js
document.getElementById('download').click();
```

```html
<a id="download" href="https://assets.entrepreneur.com/content/16x9/822/20150721193719-solshero3.jpeg" download hidden></a>
```

Play with it: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ryvwu8cf/)

But if you really can't have the *download* attribute: [Play this then.](http://jsfiddle.net/yvd3rfg5/1/)

Good luck!!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `anchor` element on click of the image and use `.click()` to trigger the click on that `anchor` even if its not attach to your page.

And if this still violate the requirement, then you may have to achieve it with server-side works.

See [Change name of download in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049259/change-name-of-download-in-javascript/10049272#10049272)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // Fake image for testment
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = 300;
  canvas.height = 200;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 100);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'cyan';
  ctx.fillText('test', 50, 50);
  
  var makeImageDownloadable = function(image, name) {
    
    image.addEventListener('click', function() {     
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = image.src;
      // may need to check the datatype, or just write image to another tmp canvas first.
      a.download = name + '.png';
      a.click();
     });
  };
  
  
  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector('#holder').appendChild(image);
    makeImageDownloadable(image, 'testimage');
  };
  image.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  
};
```

```html
<div id="holder"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `HTML5` download attribute.

```html
 <a href="http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg" download="my_download.png"><img src="http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg">
     </a>
```

I am unsure of browser compatibility in this,better soultion would be to include server side scripts too.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k2rear94/

Comment: @kcube I think so,what am i missing ?

Comment: @klausruprecht Are you not using HTML 5? If not, can you use AJAX?

Comment: I use HTML5 but my img is created dynamically and also from a different page so I can't put attributes to the tags. I can use AJAX

Comment: @klausruprecht You can add the download attribute even if element is loaded dynamically. Even better,if you can use AJAX ,just get a download link of the file ,and then just do `<a href='your_link' target='_blank' />` ?

Comment: the whole tag is created dynamically. Does that still work then? do you mean what kcube suggested?

Comment: @klausruprecht Not exactly,**IF the image is shown on page load**,then you can add the `download` attribute using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

if u want this to be dynamic, try this.

```
$("SomeElement").onclick = function(){
$("<a id='tmp' href='link' download ></a>).appendTo("body");
$("#tmp").click();
$("#tmp").remove();
}
```

But remember, download attribute is not supported in IE.

Comment: Thanks, i don't quite understand, so I click on the element and that creates the attribute into the img? do you mean like this http://fiddle.jshell.net/sf7L8r3p/ ?

Comment: if u don't want a static a tag on your page, this will append it on click event of your element to the body, trigger click event on a tag which would initiate the download, then remove the element from DOM. But this would be of no help if you are in IE.