# Append current date to filename on download

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to change filename on client's side by appending current date and time to it?
Chome appends to files (number) if files are duplicates. I wonder if it could be possible to append current date.

Comment: Not with JavaScript, you would need server-side scripting for this. (Or rather, you can do it by manipulating the `download` attribute on `<a>` elements, but [not in all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download).)

Comment: Addition to @Amadan 's comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049259/change-name-of-download-in-javascript