# How to fix javascript to change image file name from "download" to something else for example "test.png"? HTML

Tags: javascript, html, function, canvas, replace

Here is my html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script src="signature.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="canvas">
<canvas class="roundCorners" id="newSignature"
style="position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 1px solid #c4caac;"></canvas>
</div>
<script>signatureCapture();</script>
<button type="button" onclick="signatureSave()">Save signature</button>
<button type="button" onclick="signatureClear()">Clear signature</button>
<img id="saveSignature" alt="Saved image png" hidden/>
<script>
var img = document.images[0];
img.onclick = function() {
    var url = img.src.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is javascript file:

```
function signatureCapture() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("newSignature");
//next record was commented
//window.open(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
context.fillStyle = "#fff";
context.strokeStyle = "#444";
context.lineWidth = 1.5;
context.lineCap = "round";
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

var disableSave = true;
var pixels = [];
var cpixels = [];
var xyLast = {};
var xyAddLast = {};
var calculate = false;

{   //functions
        function remove_event_listeners() {
        canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', on_mousemove, false);
        canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
        canvas.removeEventListener('touchmove', on_mousemove, false);
        canvas.removeEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);
        document.body.removeEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
        document.body.removeEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);
}

    function get_coords(e) {
        var x, y;
        if (e.changedTouches && e.changedTouches[0]) {
            var offsety = canvas.offsetTop || 0;
            var offsetx = canvas.offsetLeft || 0;
            x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX - offsetx;
            y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY - offsety;
        } else if (e.layerX || 0 == e.layerX) {
            x = e.layerX;
            y = e.layerY;
        } else if (e.offsetX || 0 == e.offsetX) {
            x = e.offsetX;
            y = e.offsetY;
        }
        return {
            x : x,
            y : y
        };
};

    function on_mousedown(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', on_mousemove, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', on_mousemove, false);
        document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', on_mouseup, false);
        document.body.addEventListener('touchend', on_mouseup, false);
        empty = false;
        var xy = get_coords(e);
        context.beginPath();
        pixels.push('moveStart');
        context.moveTo(xy.x, xy.y);
        pixels.push(xy.x, xy.y);
        xyLast = xy;
    };

    function on_mousemove(e, finish) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var xy = get_coords(e);
        var xyAdd = {
            x : (xyLast.x + xy.x) / 2,
            y : (xyLast.y + xy.y) / 2
        };

    if (calculate) {
            var xLast = (xyAddLast.x + xyLast.x + xyAdd.x) / 3;
            var yLast = (xyAddLast.y + xyLast.y + xyAdd.y) / 3;
            pixels.push(xLast, yLast);
        } else {
        calculate = true;
        }
        context.quadraticCurveTo(xyLast.x, xyLast.y, xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
        pixels.push(xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
        context.stroke();
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(xyAdd.x, xyAdd.y);
        xyAddLast = xyAdd;
        xyLast = xy;
    };

    function on_mouseup(e) {
        remove_event_listeners();
        disableSave = false;
        context.stroke();
        pixels.push('e');
        calculate = false;
    };
}
canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', on_mousedown, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', on_mousedown, false);
}



function signatureSave() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("newSignature");// save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

document.getElementById("saveSignature").src = dataURL;
var url = img.src.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
location.href = url;
};


function signatureClear() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("newSignature");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

The problem is when i push button "Save signature", file saving with name "download". Every time i'm pushing this button, function saving file with new name: like "download (1)" 
What i want to do is set name by default, for example "test.png", and file become replaced by new file with the same name:  "test.png".

Comment: You can either create an `<a>` with download property, or solve it server side, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049259/change-name-of-download-in-javascript/10049272#10049272

Comment: my href looks like this: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQAAAH0CAYAAADL1t+KAAAgAElEQVR4Xu2dC9CWRfn/F01TaTInBbKhFKyhGZ....

Comment: every time i'm pushing "Save signature", it's creating new link.

Comment: Created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgh4a5nv/2/) for you, go see how you can make it with customized filename.